# How to display a button when the DOM is completely rendered

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a page that has 2 grids, and I want to make the button "export excel" visible only after the two grids are completely loaded. This grids are inside of child components as you can see on HTML bellow

```
<p-tabPanel header="Validated">
        <input type="button" name="button" value="" [hidden]="!ready"  (click)="showDialog()" title="Export Excel" class="export_Excel_Button"/>
        <gr-report-result-validated-source></gr-report-result-validated-source>
        <br>
        <gr-report-result-validated-target></gr-report-result-validated-target>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Discrepancies">
        <input type="button" name="button" value=""  title="Export Excel" [hidden]="!ready" (click)="showDialog()" class="export_Excel_Button"/>
        <gr-report-result-discrep-source></gr-report-result-discrep-source>
        <br>
        <gr-report-result-discrep-target></gr-report-result-discrep-target>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="GAPS">
            <input type="button" name="button" value=""  title="Export Excel" [hidden]="!ready" (click)="showDialog()" class="export_Excel_Button"/>
         <gr-report-result-gap></gr-report-result-gap> 
    </p-tabPanel>
```

ts

```
export class ReportResultComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
   constructor(private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute,private service:ReportService ) { }
 ready:boolean=false;

    @ViewChild(ReportResultGapComponent) rrGapsComp;
    @ViewChild(ReportResultValidatedSourceComponent) rrValidatedSource;
    @ViewChild(ReportResultValidatedTargetComponent) rrValidatedTarget;
    @ViewChild(ReportResultDiscrepSourceComponent) rrDiscrepanciesSource;
    @ViewChild(ReportResultDiscrepTargetComponent) rrDiscrepanciesTarget;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.reportInfo=this.service.getData()
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.ready=true
    }

}
```

I tried this approach but the button is being displayed before the grids are completely loaded

[image]

Comment: Could you listen to an event generate from your grid component when content is loaded ? If yes, display button with `*ngIf` when content is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<ng-component *ngIf="isLoaded">
your code
</ng-component>
```

in your ts

```
isLoaded=false

      ngAfterViewInit(){
           this.isLoaded=true;
        }
```

Comment: `this.isLoaded = true` must be in `ngAfterViewInit()` as the button is in Child components. Just asking ?